# Bash script to run php script

Tags: php, bash, shell, cron

I have a php script that I want to be run using a bash script, so I can use Cron to run the php script every minute or so.

As far as I'm aware I need to create the bash script to handle the php script which will then allow me to use the Cron tool/timer.

So far I was told I need to put:

```
#!/pathtoscript/testphp.php
```

at the start of my php script. Im not sure what to do from here...

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1347635/13036) worked for me

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you have PHP installed as a command line tool (try issuing `php` to the terminal and see if it works), your shebang (`#!`) line needs to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Put that at the top of your script, make it executable (`chmod +x myscript.php`), and make a Cron job to execute that script (same way you'd execute a bash script).

You can also use `php myscript.php`.

Comment: If you're going to use a shebang for command line usage, you REALLY should use "**#!/usr/bin/env php**", as it allows the script to be more portable, since PHP may not always be installed in "/usr/bin/php". Make sense?

Comment: @Rican7: ordinarily, yes, but the OP wants to run this as a cron job, which will have a reduced environment. If php isn't at /usr/bin/php, `env` may not be able to find it anyway. Multiple SO Q/As address this (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608, for example).

Answer (score 25):

Sometimes PHP is placed in non standard location so it's probably better first locate it and then try to execute.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PHP=`which php`
$PHP /path/to/php/file.php
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/env php` does exactly this (that's most of the point of using `env`), with the added advantage that you can put your php code directly in the bash script, without having to write an additional 'file.php'.

Answer (score 13):

A previous poster said..

> *If you have PHP installed as a command line tool… your shebang (#!) line needs to look like this: `#!/usr/bin/php`*

While this *could* be true… just because you can type in `php` does NOT necessarily mean that's where php is going to be...  `/usr/bin/php` is A common location… but as with any shebang… it needs to be tailored to YOUR `env`.

a quick way to find out WHERE YOUR particular executable is located on your `$PATH`, try..
➜`which -a php` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, which for me looks like..

`php is /usr/local/php5/bin/php`
`php is /usr/bin/php`
`php is /usr/local/bin/php`
`php is /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/php`

The first one is the default i'd get if I just typed in php at a command prompt… but I can use any of them in a shebang, or directly…  You can also combine the executable name with `env`, as is often seen, but I don't really know much about / trust *that*.  XOXO.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to set :

```
/usr/bin/php path_to_your_php_file
```

in your crontab.

Answer (score 9):

I'm pretty sure something like this is what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/sh

php /pathToScript/script.php
```

Save that with your desired script name (such as runPHP.sh) and give it execution rights, then you can use it however you want.

Edit: You might as well not use a bash script at all and just add the "php ..." command to the crontab, if I'm not mistaken.

Good luck!

Comment: In most environments you can't simply call `php youscript.php` but have to figure out the right path. E.g. using the whole path `/usr/bin/php myscript.php` or figuring it out dynamically by calling `which php` and writing the result in a variable you use later on.

Answer (score 4):

The bash script should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php /path/to/php/file.php
```

You need the php executable (usually found in /usr/bin) and the path of the php script to be ran. Now you only have to put this bash script on crontab and you're done!

Answer (score 2):

> a quick way to find out WHERE YOUR particular executable is located on your $PATH, try.

Even quicker way to find out where `php` is ...

```
whereis php
```

I'm running `debian` and above command showing me

```
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: returning output "unknown whereis"

Comment: You'll have to install `whereis` if its not by default.

Comment: i have installed ffmpeg on windows system, it works by command line but does not work by php while exec command is enabled. I have also restarted computer and xampp after installing ffmpeg. FYI i have setup environment variables of ffmpeg also. Kindly help, if you can. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You should create a separate poat for that question mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything in your bash script than run the php one, you could simply run the php script from cron with a command like /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/file.php.

Answer (score 0):

I found php-cgi on my server. And its on environment path so I was able to run from anywhere. I executed succesfuly `file.php` in my bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
php-cgi ../path/file.php
```

And the script returned this after php script was executed:

**X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.1 
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8**

done!

By the way, check first if it works by checking the version issuing the command `php-cgi -v`

Answer (score 0):

Create file.php with first line in files:
 file.php(#!/bin/php)
 file.sh(#!/bin/bash).
Check installed php.Run command in terminal:

```
which php
```

If set there will be an answer:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Run file.php with command:

```
php file.php
```

if the file has started then you can write this command to file.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
run_php=`php file.php`
echo $run_php
```

Be careful ' and ` different!!!