# Load PHP Module only in CLI

Tags: php, apache, pthreads, osx-elcapitan

Is it possible to load a PHP module only in CLI. I am trying to enable pthreads in CLI only but it gets enabled in Apache as well and crashes the server. I am using Homebrew to install php7 and php7-pthreads. Apache Loads the modules from /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/ and everything inside /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d

I created a folder named CLI and moved the ext-pthreads.ini inside it but it didn't work.

Comment: You could completely separate the PHP install by downloading a ZIP from php.net and putting it somewhere else for use by your CLI.

Comment: @pgmann thank you but this will create further issues to keep php versions in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use command line options for that:

```
php -d extension="[yourExtension]"
```

If you wrap it in a bash (or .bat) file you only have to specify it once.

**Update**

You could use something like (not tested):

```
#!/bin/sh

php -d extension="[yourExtension]" ./pathToYour/script.php
```

For an extended explanation, please see: [Bash script to run php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506913/bash-script-to-run-php-script)

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit more. I know what php -d does but not fully sure how to wrap it in a bash file. Does this mean that I can put `php -d extension=[yourExtension]` in a file and point .bash_profile to it ?

Comment: Also: if my answer is helpful to you, feel free to upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for leading me to the right direction. I duplicated php.ini that was inside  /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/ and renamed it to php-cli.ini and enabled pthreads there.