# How can I run PHP script in the sh file?

Tags: php, centos, sh

I have sh file with below content :

```
#!/bin/sh -x
pgrep -x php >/dev/null && echo "Process found" || nohup php /home/zimakar/public_html/index.php robot index 123123123 > /home/zimakar/robot.log &
```

My operating system is Centos 7.

I'm searching PHP process and if not running, so I run PHP file again.

My PHP file is a robot and listens to the socket

There are problems in running the file, example log the error ini_set for the session.

Also, I change the permission of the file to executive mode.

Tip: When I'm running the robot in CommandLine, it's working good

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506913/bash-script-to-run-php-script

Comment: @ArashShiri Ooom no I didn't try it,Thanks

Comment: @OmidAghakhani : You are labelling your question as _bash_, but your script is sh. ... _There are problems _ : I don't see any description of the problems in your question.

Comment: @user1934428 what is different between bash and sh?

Comment: Two different languages, which have a lot of syntax in common. If you write a program in sh, chances are good that it would work also in bash. The opposite is not true.

Comment: Good idea to edit it, but the script you posted is still `sh`, while the title says _bash_ ....

Comment: @user1934428 Oh yes, I updated it, Thanks

Comment: On the first glance, your program looks good to me. What are you asking? The only problem I see is when you have several php processes running, how you can be sure that you are monitoring the right one.

Comment: @user1934428 Because only one process exist from PHP

Comment: @user1934428 I was forced use wget for run my robot "wget http://example.com/robot/index/123123123 >> /home/zimakar/robot.log"

Comment: Then - what's your problem/question? You just describe what you are doing, but I don't understand why you are not happy with it...

Comment: Leave it, I think that explain it badly